# how to copy all the database tables from one schema to another on the same server?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to copy all the MYSQL database tables present in one schema to another using MYSQLworkbench?I read on other posts about using `Dataimport`
but its not clear as to how to use it?can anyone provide pointers on how to do it?is there a better tool to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data import/export wizards are pretty straight forward: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-management.html. What you need is to specify the source for the dump you made (either from a folder or a self contained dump file). Then specify a different schema to import in and off you go.

Comment: It should probably be noted that if the dump file includes a schema, it will always import into that one regardless of what you select for the default in the drop-down.